# Android animated live wallpaper

Tags: android, animation, live-wallpaper

I have a sequence of png files and I want to produce an animated livewallpaper to be published in google market (play).

How can I do that?

Comment: Read tutorials: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html